# How do I form question tags for these examples?

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

> 1. It's been a long time since you've seen him, HASN'T IT?

This is how I would form the question tag BUT I was told the correct form is
"ISN'T IT?" and I really can't figure out why. I need to understand the reason.

> 2. They've got too much luggage, HAVEN'T THEY?

This one is correct, right? I mean, I use "haven't" with "have GOT".

> 3. They have too much luggage, DON'T THEY?

I use "don't" because it's just "have" here.

Answer (score 1):

Tags and tenses for your examples:

**Present Perfect Example**
1) **It's been** a long time since you've seen him, **hasn't it?** [right, tense: present perfect] The tag verb is has.

**Two Forms of the present tense** with the same exact meaning:

2) **They've got** too much luggage, **haven't they**? [right, tense: simple present] the tag verb is have.

3) They **have** too much luggage, **don't they**? [right, tense: simple present] the tag verb is do

In English, there are two forms to have (meaning possessing): to have/have got, in the present tense. for **have**, the auxiliary is **do**. for **have got** the auxiliary is **have**.

So, sentences 2) and 3) have the same meaning but different forms. Have got is typically spoken not written. You can see the tags in the examples.

Word of warning: **in British English**, **have got** can be present tense or present perfect: They've got [received] a lot of letters recently. But it is not present perfect in the sample sentence; it is simple present.

Answer (score 0):

> It's been a long time since you've seen him, hasn't it?

Since the tense of this sentence is present perfect, you should use "**hasn't it?**" as you've mentioned. (It's refers to *it has*)

> They've got too much luggage, haven't they?

The tense of this sentence is present perfect, so you should use "**haven't they?**"

> They have too much luggage, don't they?

"Have" is the main verb of this sentence and the tense is simple present, so you should use "**don't they?**"

---

The verb "have got" in the second sentence is in the form of present perfect. Take a look at [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get?show=0&t=1373859729) definition from Merriam-Webster:

> a : have —used in the present perfect tense form with present meaning

or [this](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=get) one from American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language:

> 16 a. To have current possession of. Used in the present perfect form
>   with the meaning of the present

Comment: Thanks so much! But...when HAVE GOT means possession, do I have to use "haven't they?" or "don't they"? I think it's "haven't they?" anyway  or am I wrong?

Comment: @Raaffaa Although "have + got" means possession, this form of the verb is present perfect. Take a look at this definition from [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get?show=0&t=1373859729): *"a : have —used in the present perfect tense form with present meaning"* or this one from [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=get): *"a. To have current possession of. Used in the present perfect form with the meaning of the present"*

Comment: @Lambie He had asked the question before your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Tag question should match the verb (is/have) if you are using *isn't it* or *hasn't it*.

> It's been a long time since you've seen him, ...

The contraction in this sentence expands to:

> It *has* been a long time since you've seen him, ...

so *hasn't it* is right.

> It *is* been a long time since you've seen him, ...

This is NOT right.